# spring-cloud-dataflow JDBC authentication

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Spring Cloud Dataflow is awesome. It's marvelous and working like a charm. 
Only problem we have encountered in missing JDBC authentication. FileBasedAuthetication is not safe and everyone do not LDAP. Huge chunk of users still prefer to use JDBC authentication.

It will be of great support if you help me with JDBC authentication.  Do let me know how to implement it, any document or URL be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

You can still add a custom JDBC authentication (via any Spring Boot managed SecurityConfigurer - GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter) and have it as a bean in your custom Data Flow server configuration(by running it via `@EnableDataFlowServer`).

You can also contribute the same to Spring Cloud Data Flow.

Thanks!

Comment: Ilayaperumal Gopinathan, sure i will give a try.  I will also contribute it back to Spring Cloud Data Flow community.

Comment: I've successfully implemented JDBC authentication. How to contribute it back to the community? Shall i create a separate project or update the existing projects? Right now, I have added classes to "spring-cloud-common-security-config-web" and  "spring-cloud-dataflow-server-core".

Comment: Hi Shaikh, Nice to know that. Please submit PRs in both the projects with your changes. Thank you!